# findById only work on model ID loopback

Tags: express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm facing an issue in acl of loopback 3.18.0 detail explanation suppose I have 2 model user (table name as user) and company (table name as company ) and in user table I have column name as company_id this company_id is foreign key in table company. When client(developer like us) uses company model  api suppose like "api/comapnys/:id" if :id parameter contain value of company_id of user table it will throw error(unauthorized). But if parameter id is model company id then it will work as expected [image: database image]  more detail from image if I use 121 as id then it throw error but if I use 1 of company id then I will work (if I login using bipin@gmail.com credential whose company_id is 121 )

In user.js relations code like:

```
"relations": {
    "companys": {
        "type": "hasOne",
       "model": "company",
  "foreignKey": "company_id"
         }
},
```

And in company.json relations like:

```
"relations": {
       "users": {
           "type": "belongsTo",
          "model": "user",
     "foreignKey": "company_id"
     }
},
  "acls": [
   {
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
},

{
  "accessType": "READ",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": ["find","findById"]
 }
],
```

Is this expected behavior or issue in acl if yes how I can pass company model id for any authenticated user in front end  i.e if user login then every time he has company model id.

Comment: Can you please try to change in your relations `"users": {
           "type": "belongsTo",
          "model": "company",
     "foreignKey": "user_id"
     }` and "companys": {
        "type": "hasOne",
       "model": "user",
  "foreignKey": "company_id"
         }

Comment: @AnouarKacem hii... yes i will try :)